# node.js dynamic javascript execution performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, file, awk

I'd like to execute an arbitrary - user supplied - piece of javascript code on each line of a file. I created a simple node command line application, that will - as an example - just take each line and will output its length:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// eachline.js - execute some js per line in a file

var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline');
    vm = require('vm');

var args = process.argv.slice(2);

if (args.length < 1) {
    console.log("Usage: eachline.js FILENAME")
    process.exit(code=1)
}

var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(args[0]),
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});

var context = vm.createContext({});
// this snippet should be user supplied, arbitrary javascript
var script = vm.createScript('output = input.length');

rd.on('line', function(line) {
    context.input = line;
    script.runInContext(context);
    console.log(context.output);
});
```

The performance is not optimal. For a file with 1 million lines, it takes several minutes:

```
$ time ./eachline.js 1M.txt > /dev/null

real    4m14.366s
user    4m12.200s
sys     0m4.545s
```

With `awk` this simple operation takes about five seconds. With a [similar program](https://github.com/miku/ottily#performance), that executes arbitrary javascript a bit more than ten seconds.

I haven't worked with node before, so the program above is my first uneducated guess at a solution. How could I improve performance?

Edit: Above source code in a gist: https://gist.github.com/miku/31864156938fcd0c8430

---

PS. Goal is to have a program that can run arbitrary javascript on each line of a file fast.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve? It's really not clear from the question as posted. Why do you want to run code for each line in a separate context?

Comment: The user should be able to define the js snippet to execute on each line dynamically. `vm.runInNewContext` was the method I found, which allowed to pass some context to the execution (here, the input `line`), and from which I could get the result back (here, the `output`).

Comment: Did you try just creating a context *once* and re-using that for each line?

Comment: Well, if you read the documentation for the "vm" module, it's got lots of warnings about instability and imperfect security. Also creating a million new contexts, re-parsing the code for each one, is probably a big part of your performance problem. It would be much better to establish some sort of message-passing relationship with the untrusted code. (I realize that you can't do that with the "vm" mechanisms.)

Comment: Oh wait - yes, what @mscdex said - you can use `vm.createContext()` to create a context, `vm.createScript()` to pre-parse a script, and then `vm.runInContext()` to re-use the same context over and over. That would be a good thing to try, and it'd require fairly minimal changes to your code.

Comment: @mscdex, thanks for the hint. Updates my question with code that reuses context - which cuts execution time from 6min to 4min.

Comment: @Pointy, yes I read the caveats of the "vm" module.

Comment: Seems to me the `vm.runInContext()` is a blocking operation. _Maybe_ you could run it asynchronously using the async module? https://www.npmjs.org/package/async

Comment: Would this be better on [codereview.se]?

Comment: The `async` module won't magically make blocking operations non-blocking. `async` is just for managing/organizing *asynchronous* operations.

Comment: @mscdex I know, but it should perform more than one operation at a time and thus reduce the time taken to execute

Comment: `async` doesn't perform multiple synchronous operations in parallel because it's all executed in the same main thread. Also the comparison with ottily isn't exactly comparing apples to apples since ottily forks processing according to how many CPUs/cores you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var context = vm.createContext({});
// this snippet should be user supplied, arbitrary javascript
var script = vm.createScript('(function (input) { return input.length; })');
var fn = script.runInContext(context);

rd.on('line', function(line) {
    console.log(fn(line));
});
```

The idea is to wrap provided expression in a function, evaluate the script and then use the function. I think v8 doesn't optimize code inside `script` because it is not supposed to run more than once.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to throw a `ReferenceError`: https://gist.github.com/miku/31864156938fcd0c8430#file-err-md

Comment: you need to wrap code in a function and pass input as an argument: `'(function (input) { return input.length; })'`

Comment: Sorry, I overread the closure the first time. This indeed gives an enormous speedup, from over 4min to 23s.